# Bootstrap, Input type=date

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap

Buenas tardes estimados,

Tengo una pregunta alguien sabe como cambiar el diseno del calendario que aparece al presionar un Input type=Date en bootstrap?

Esto lo quiero hacer porque cuando veo mi formulario en un dispositivo móvil, escoger el ano no es intuitivo, las personas creen que tienen que ir retrocediendo mes a mes hasta encontrar la fecha que desean (ano de nacimiento). adjunto una foto de como me aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si bien es un hecho que al presionar el ano, me aparecerá la lista para escogerlo, la mayoría de las personas a las que le he mostrado no encuentran esto fácil de interpretar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando el siguiente CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

El codigo para mi formulario es>

```
<section id="content">
            <div class="container clearfix">

                <div class="heading-block m-t-45 center wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.9s">
                    
                        <b>**Nota: Toda la Información aquí proporcionada será tratada con confidencialidad.</b></span>
                
                                   
                </div>

                <div class="row bottommargin-sm c-azul">
                    <div class="container clearfix">


                        <form class="nobottommargin" method="post" id="bolsa" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="formpdf.php" >
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="puesto">Puesto al que aplica:<small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="puesto" name="puesto" value=""  class="sm-form-control  is-valid">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="nombre1">Primer nombre:<small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombre1" name="nombre1" value=""  class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col_one_third col_last c-azul">
                                    <label for="nombre2">Segundo nombre:<small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombre2" name="nombre2" value=""  class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="apellido1">Primer apellido:<small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="apellido1" name="apellido1" value=""  class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="apellido2">Segundo apellido:<small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="apellido2" name="apellido2" value=""  class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul col_last ">
                                    <label for="genero">género :<small>*</small></label>
                                    <select name="selectgenero" id="genero" class="dropdown-trigger btn " ="">
                                    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                    <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                                    <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option> 
                                   </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="estatura">Estatura (Metros)<small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="estatura" placeholder="1.80" name="estatura" value=""  class="">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="peso">Peso (Libras)<small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="peso" placeholder="180" name="peso" value=""  class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_one_third col_last c-azul">
                                    <label for="identificacion">Número de identidad <small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="identificacion" name="identificacion"  placeholder="0000-0000-00000" value="" class="sm-form-control">
                                </div>
                                

                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="phone">Teléfono<small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="0000-0000"  name="phone" value="" class="sm-form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="nacionalidad">Nacionalidad<small></small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nacionalidad" placeholder="Hondureña"  name="nacionalidad" value="" class="sm-form-control">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col_one_third col_last c-azul">
                                    <label for="nacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento<small></small></label>
                                    <input type="date" id="nacimiento"  name="nacimiento"  class="sm-form-control">
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                <input type="button" name="next"  class="next1 btn btn-primary nomargin" value="Siguiente" />
                           </fieldset>

                        </form>     

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Alguien me hecha una mano?
Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: He buscado en la documentación pero no me aparece algo que explique como modificar ese diseno, alguna solución que podría utilizar sin tener que cambiarme a otro framework?

Comment: No necesitas cambiarte a otro framework, puedes buscar varias opciones de datepickers. Como hay tantas opciones, te aconsejo hacer una búsqueda similar a "datepicker UI", y escoger el que más se ajuste a tus necesidades. El de material-ui, en lo personal, me gusta bastante

Comment: @Jheyman Mejia, material-ui es para Angular no? yo no estoy usando ese framew...

Comment: El componente que mencionas en tu pregunta no es nativo de Bootstrap, estás usando algún plugin, ¿cuál? Por el diseño parece `md-bootstrap` (Material Design), ¿podrías aclarar esto además de la versión? Tambien es necesario un [mcve] para poder reproducir tu problema. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estoy editando la pregunta

Comment: Yo tengo un problema similar. No depende del framework, a mi el input=date me aparece similar en móvil y no es nada intuitivo seleccionar el año. No encuentro forma de hacerlo más accesible a los usuarios.